# Trouble printing out results of averaging an array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

```
using System;

namespace RainfallHW {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string [] months;
            double[] rain;

            months = new string [12] {  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
            rain = new double[12];

            for (int i = 0; i < rain.Length; i++) {
                Console.Write("Rainfall in {0}: ", months[i]);
                rain[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                while (rain[i] < 0) {
                    Console.Write("Rainfall in {0}: ", months[i]);
                    rain[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    double avg;
                    double sum = 0;
                    for (int x = 0; x < rain.Length; x++) {
                        sum = sum + rain[i];
                    }
                    avg = sum / 12;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Average Month Rain: ", avg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to take in the rainfall amount for each month and average it out. I cannot get it to print out my result for the average. I am relatively new to arrays and loops and I am just not too sure where I am going wrong here.

I am currently getting no output whatsoever. The program closes as soon as the inputs for each month is entered.

Comment: Please indicate exactly what isn't working (for example, what output *do* you get).

Comment: it looks like you are doing your calculation inside the retry loop.

Comment: If you are closing so quickly, you should probably put a try/catch around it or look for exceptions in the output window

Comment: you should attach a debugger and run through the code step by step.

Comment: @ADB glad you got this resolved! Please take a look at the updated code on my answer. Your existing while loop to check for input will have some issues with inputs that aren't numbers. It needs to be updated to first check that the input is a valid number, THEN that the number is valid (in your case, > 0).

Comment: @levelonehuman Thanks! This makes the code even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously messed up with curly braces. After avg-calculating block is moved to its right place, it starts working:

```
string [] months;
double[] rain;

months = new string [12] {  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
rain = new double[12];

for (int i = 0; i < rain.Length; i++) {
    Console.Write("Rainfall in {0}: ", months[i]);
    rain[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    while (rain[i] < 0) {
        Console.Write("Rainfall in {0}: ", months[i]);
        rain[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
double avg;
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rain.Length; i++) {
    sum = sum + rain[i];
}
avg = sum / 12;
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Average Month Rain: " + avg);
```

Comment: The average still will not print out. The input is all okay. The output is "Average Month Rain:        ". No actual result

Comment: Sorry, just corrected the solution. The last line should use either concatenation of strings, or string format ("Average Month Rain: {0}").

Comment: @ideafixxxer Haha, I totally missed that. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close: the code for adding up the rainfall and dividing by the number of months has to happen after the reading loop, not inside it.

Currently you do not print anything because the loop for correcting negative input encloses the code that prints the average.

You can do additions to compute `sum` as you go. Here is an outline of what you can do:

- Make a `for` loop that goes through the 12 month
- Ask for the rainfall number
- While the value entered is negative, continue asking for input
- When a non-negative value is entered, add the value to a running total
- Once the reading loop has finished, print the running total divided by 12.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Please consider my edit to the code below. The updated `while` loop should make sure an actual number is being supplied. With the existing while loop, you will throw an exception if something other than a number is input.

The issue is the code inside your `while` loop. It looks like maybe this was intended to be a "hey, you didn't put in a valid number, try again." That's fine, but the rest of your code is also inside this loop.

Instead:

```
using System;

namespace RainfallHW
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] months;
            double[] rain;
            double avg;
            double sum = 0;
            double value;
            string input;
            bool isValid = false;


            months = new string[12] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
            rain = new double[12];

            for (int i = 0; i < rain.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Rainfall in {0}: ", months[i]);

                while (!isValid)
                {
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                    //TryParse returns true if input is a number
                    //Then check for > 0
                    if (double.TryParse(input, out value) && double.Parse(input) > 0)
                    {
                        rain[i] = double.Parse(input);
                        sum += rain[i]; //update the sum here instead of its own loop
                        isValid = true;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Console.Write("Rainfall in {0}: ", months[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            avg = sum / 12;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Average Month Rain: {0}", avg);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I got from what I *think* you're trying to do. If that's not the case, please let me know and I can take another look.

The way this will run now is

`Get Input for month
    Check for invalid input
Loop through final month
Loop through rain array to compute average *annual* rainfall`

Comment: I tried to move it out of the loop but it only prints out the prompt and the "Average month rain:" but not an actual result. Also they are printed together.

Comment: @ADB Take a look at my edit, that might fix the problem for you.

Comment: I am not getting the result at all. Did i calculate the average wrong?